# Google Sheets: Script to sort and filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this sheet:

[Personal finances sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDSOz.png)

I have this script to "onEdit" sort the A and B columns:

```js
function onEdit(event){

  const ssApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ssApp.getSheetByName("Adispo");
  const editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  const columnToSortByDate = 2;
  const columnToSortByCheckbox = 1;
  const tableRange = "A5:G1000";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortByDate || editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortByCheckbox){   
    let range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( [
      { column : 1, ascending: false },
      { column : 2, ascending: false }
    ] );
  }
}
```

Now I would like not to sort the A column, **but filter it**, in order not to show the checked checkboxes:

[Wanted filtered view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNO9I.png)

It seems there's something to do with `newFilterCriteria` and `setColumnFilterCriteria`, but I really can't figure it out.

May someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started. The reference you already found yourself. I think this is enough for you to adjust to your needs.

```
function createFilter() {
  //Creating new criteria
  const filter = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .whenTextEqualTo('FALSE')
    .build();

  //Defining the sheet and range.
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').getRange('A1:B');

  //Get current filter and remove (you cannot set a filter when a filter is active)
  range.getFilter().remove();

  //Setting new filter on column 2 (B)
  range.createFilter()
    .setColumnFilterCriteria(2, filter);

}
```

Comment: Hi @RemcoE33, works perfectly fine now, thank you very much!